# How can I test earbuds to determine their quality?

Tags: headphones, performance

I bought a pair of earbuds on eBay and I'm slightly concerned that they could be a knockoff. Its pretty difficult for me to tell if they are fakes or not since I have nothing to compare the sound with, and as far as I know, it sounds fine and better than my previous earbuds.

Are there any simple methods to gauge the performance of the earbuds so I can get some numbers to compare with existing data for my earbuds? Things like impedance, frequency range, etc

Comment: What makes you think it is a "knockoff"?

Comment: @Flimzy I bought it from ebay, though the seller had a very good rep(thousands of positive reps) and a very large store, the prices were quite cheaper than retail. $40 instead of $120.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the best test will be your ears.

If they sound good to you and you feel they were worth the price then you probably got a good deal.